# What is larger? Graham's number or Googolplexian?

Tags: big-numbers, number-comparison

See [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTeJ64KD5cg) or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number) for the defination of Graham's number.

A **Googol** is defined as $10^{100}$.

A **Googolplex** is defined as $10^{\text{Googol}}$.

A **Googolplexian** is defined as $10^{\text{Googolplex}}$.

Intuitively, it seems to me that Graham's number is larger (maybe because of it's complex definition).

Can anybody prove this?

Comment: Graham's number is much **much** bigger. As in, take 3^3^3^3^... for the rest of your life, and you aren't even remotely close in any sense.

Comment: Better yet, have everyone alive from now until the universe ends, help you take 3^3^3^3^... as fast as possible. You still won't be able to reach Grahams number.

Comment: Even iterating the number of $3$'s in the power tower $3\uparrow3 \uparrow\cdots \uparrow 3$ a googol times (starting with $3^{3^3}$) will not get even close to Graham's number

Comment: This isn't really rigorous, but I use as a heuristic that pretty much any number you can reasonably define in a "normal" way (i.e., without invoking set theory or new operations or anything like that) is WAY smaller than Graham's number, and should never be compared to it. But by all means, let me know if there is some such number greater than Graham's number- that would be interesting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Googolplex can be bounded from above like a tower of exponents, so $$10^{10^{100}} < (3^3)^{10^{100}} = 3^{3\times 10^{100}} <3^{10^{101}} < 3^{(3^3)^{101}} = 3^{3^{303}} < 3^{3^{3^{3^3}}}$$ In the last step, we have used the fact that $303$ is much,much smaller than $3^{27}$. Now, take the Googolplexian.We can thus, easily check that,  $$10^{10^{10^{100}}} < (3^3)^{10^{10^{100}}} < 3^{3^{3^{3^{3^3}}}}$$ **So, Googolplexian is much smaller than a tower of exponents of $3$'s of length $6$, or in other words Googolplexian is less than $3\uparrow \uparrow6$.**(using [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://oeis.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation#Knuth.27s_up-arrow_notation).)

---

Now, compare this with just the first layer of Graham's number,i.e., $3\uparrow \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow 3$. Hope it helps.

Comment: After the first equality sign It should be $3^{3\times 10^{100}}$ instead of $3^{3\times 10^{10^{100}}}$.

Comment: @timon92 Thank you for the correction.

Comment: The inability to even conceive what $3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3$ is should be enough.  Or even drop an arrow.